# xserver-xorg-video-intel in ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

Tags: 12.04, ppa

I have two 12.04 , both update to 12.04.2 with kernel 3.2.0-43-generic.
Both are using `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` .
I find I install xserver-xorg-video-intel 2.20 in one 12.04 , 2.19 in the other 12.04.
Their systems are both updated.

```
$ apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-intel:
  Installed: 2:2.19.0-0ubuntu1~xup1
  Candidate: 2:2.19.0-0ubuntu1~xup1
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.19.0-0ubuntu1~xup1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:2.17.0-1ubuntu4.4 0
        500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:2.17.0-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages

$ apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-intel:
  Installed: 2:2.20.0-0ubuntu0~precise1
  Candidate: 2:2.20.0-0ubuntu0~precise1
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.20.0-0ubuntu0~precise1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:2.19.0-0ubuntu1~xup1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     2:2.17.0-1ubuntu4.4 0
        500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2:2.17.0-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Why can not I install 2.20 version in the other 12.04 ? In that 12.04's synaptics , I only find 2.19 version .
Why does that ppa offer differently in two systems ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version `2.20.0` is a local package on your system, because it has no source repository currently associated with it. That means, either you have installed it as a `.deb` file manually, or you had an other source temporarily added in the past. My guess is, that you had the `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/intel-graphics-updates` added to the software sources sometime earlier, did an upgrade, and later you have removed it or changed it to `ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`. Based on the exact version string of the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package, this seems obvious:

```
PPA name:       ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
Latest version: 2:2.19.0-0ubuntu1~xup1

PPA name:       ubuntu-x-swat/intel-graphics-updates
Latest version: 2:2.20.0-0ubuntu0~precise1
```

Here you can find a more recent version of this driver (2.21.6):

`ppa:glasen/intel-driver`

If you want to downgrade a package, you have to specify the exact version number to install:

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel=2:2.19.0-0ubuntu1~xup1`

Comment: Why does it down-grade to 2.19 if there is no relevant repository?

Comment: There is no automatic downgrade, the package manager always try to have the packages with the highest version number installed.

Comment: ubuntu-x-swat/intel-graphics-updates is enough stable now ?

Comment: Yes, I think so, that package is already more than 6 months old.